# Таймер для скачивания на PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, таймер

Здорова!
Как написать таймер на PHP типа, как на сайте depositfiles - *через 30 или 60 секунд начнется скачивание*(пример на картинке), если нужно использовать JS, то как это все соединить?
Однако, было бы лучше использовать чисто PHP.[image: пример]
А также можно ли управлять скоростью отсчета таймера? типа чтоб быстрее или медленнее считал?

Comment: Таймер через js делать, через setTimeout или setInterval. А ссылку на скачивание или ajax'ом из сервера получать, или на странице спрятать

Comment: сможете пример написать?

Comment: `А также можно ли управлять скоростью отсчета таймера? типа чтоб быстрее или медленнее считал?` - 10 секунд это и есть 10 секунд... или вы хотите что бы 10 сек пролетало за одну?

Comment: @iKey хаха))
ну  типа да, или наоборот , чтоб 10 секунд шли как 20, типа медленнее в 2 раза

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выглядит примерно так:

```
function download() {
  // fetch code
}

setTimeout(download, 60000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вам нужен **JavaScript**

Например так:

```js
setTimeout(() => alert('Начинаем скачивать'), 3000);
```

```html
Скачивание скоро начнется
```

Источник: https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: можно и без JS устроить )

Comment: @teran а как? вот  чтобы он на странице через хотя бы каждые 2 секунды менял цифру? типа было сначала 1 , а потом через 2 секунды эта однёрка превратилась в 2, потом снова через 2 секунды  в тройку и т.д?

Comment: @ThekingArthur можно не значит, что нужно.